# Linux equivalent of WaitCommEvent

Tags: c++, c, linux

I want to do an evented read on Serial port which will run only when the data is available.

I have tried `sigaction` but it causes problem when making a highly threaded application, also `sleep` function seem to work incorrectly according to many forums.

So I am looking for a similar way as in windows `WaitCommEvent` that is used in MSDN.

Comment: C **or** C++; not both. These are different languages.

Comment: Everything is a file. Use [select()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/select).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: considering this is Linux, `poll`/`epoll` might be better suited.

Comment: The Unix and Linux APIs will probably seem weird at first if you are already familiar with the Windows and Dos APIs, but after a little while you will likely find that the Unix and Linux APIs are simpler, more flexible, and easier to remember.  You can see all of the system calls available by exploring section 2 of the man pages.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: for the current problem, it does not matter whether it is C or C++. The question is about what is the appropriate system call on Linux, and it will be declared and used the same in C and C++. But I must admit that I would have used only the C tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical equivalents for linux systems is to use [`poll()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) or [`select()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html).

Workings are different of course.

Comment: There are many other ways, e.g. a seperate thread, `epoll`, etc. I think the question is too proad/opiniated.